# Can JSP and PHP exist on the same site?

Tags: java, jsp

Hello I am wondering if you can have a page that has both PHP and JSP on the same page? Is that possible? Or would is it more that you have to have a entire site coded in one of the languages.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can use apache with mod_proxy. with this example you'll redirect all calls to /tomcat to your tomcat root directory.

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass /tomcat ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/
ProxyPassReverse /tomcat/ http://www.example.com/tomcat/
```

for more details check. http://rimuhosting.com/mod_jk2_and_mod_proxy_ajp.jsp